# Fixed component position based on size and location of other component

Tags: angularjs

I have a Map component which has a static position and lays on top of some other stuff (don't mind).
I have a sidebar component which has it's own relative position within that 'other stuff'.

What I need is to set an fixed position of my Map component based on sidebar location on the screen and watch any changes on the sidebar location or Window resize.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

usage:

```
<div id="map" fixed top-left="$ctrl.topLeft()" bottom-right="$ctrl.bottomRight()">map</div>
```

implementation:

```
var app = angular.module('app')

app.directive('fixed', [ '$window', function($window) {
    function position(scope, element) {
        var topLeft = scope.topLeft();
        var bottomRight = scope.bottomRight();
        element.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            left: topLeft.x - (element.outerWidth(true) - element.outerWidth()) / 2,
            top: topLeft.y - (element.outerHeight(true) - element.outerHeight()) / 2,
            width: bottomRight.x - topLeft.x - (element.outerWidth(true) - element.innerWidth()),
            height: bottomRight.y - topLeft.y - (element.outerHeight(true) - element.innerHeight())
        });
    }

    return {
        scope : {
            topLeft: '&',
            bottomRight: '&'
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attr) {
            position(scope, element);
            $($window).resize(function() {
                position(scope, element);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```